# Making hover intersection effect in FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I want to make an intersection hover effect in a timeline calendar.

I made another table on top of calendar and the intersection hover effect work using CSS.
It works fine but if we have event that has a description in multiple lines (or multiple events at the same time) that row height is different and my hover effect doesn't work OK – it overlaps as seen in next image. The code is available at https://codepen.io/timotejmedved/pen/vYVepaQ?editors=0110

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.6,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    resourceGroupField: 'building',
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    resources: [
      { id: '1', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '2', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '3', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '4', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '5', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '6', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '11', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '21', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '31', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '41', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '51', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '61', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '111', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '211', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '311', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '411', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '511', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '611', title: 'Resource C' },

      { id: '19', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '29', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '39', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '49', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '59', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '69', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '191', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '291', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '319', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '419', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '519', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '619', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '1191', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '2191', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '3191', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '4191', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '5191', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '6191', title: 'Resource C' },
    ],
    events: [
      { resourceId: '1', start: '2023-05-02T02:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
      { resourceId: '2', start: '2023-05-02T05:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T09:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
      { resourceId: '3', start: '2023-05-02T03:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T08:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
      { resourceId: '4', start: '2023-05-02T06:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T12:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
      { resourceId: '5', start: '2023-05-02T08:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T13:00:00', title: 'event 5' },
      { resourceId: '6', start: '2023-05-02T10:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T14:00:00', title: 'event 6' },
      { resourceId: '1', start: '2023-05-02T13:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T18:00:00', title: 'event 7' },
      { resourceId: '2', start: '2023-05-02T10:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T14:00:00', title: 'event 8' },
      { resourceId: '3', start: '2023-05-02T08:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T12:30:00', title: 'event 9' }
    ],

    eventContent: function (arg) {

      var event = arg.event;

      var customHtml = '';

      customHtml += "<span class='r10 font-xxs font-bold' style='overflow: hidden;'>" + event.title + "</span>";

      customHtml += "<span class='r10 highlighted-badge font-xxs font-bold'> <br/> jkaSDHLKJahsdlkjAHS</span>";


      return { html: customHtml }
    },

    eventDidMount: function (info) {

    },





    viewDidMount: function (info) {
      var rowHeights = document.querySelectorAll('.fc-timeline-body  .fc-scrollgrid-sync-table  tbody tr');
  
      var numResources = document.querySelectorAll('table.fc-datagrid-body tbody tr').length;

      var resourcesHeights = document.querySelectorAll('table.fc-datagrid-body tbody tr')

      console.log(resourcesHeights.item(1))
      console.log(resourcesHeights.values())

      var tt = resourcesHeights.item(0);

      const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(tt);
      var height = compStyles.getPropertyValue("height");
      console.log(height)

      // create new table element
      var hoverTable = document.createElement('table');
      hoverTable.classList.add('hover-table');

      // get the main table element
      var mainTable = document.querySelector('.fc-timeline-body table');

      console.log("maintable");
      console.log(mainTable.offsetHeight * 3);


      //var cellWidth = mainTable.querySelector('td').offsetWidth;
      //var rowHeight = mainTable.querySelector('tr').offsetHeight;
      var cellWidth = 30;
      // var rowHeight = 34.4;
      var rowHeight = 34;
      //console.log(rowHeight)

      // set the position, width, and height of the hover table
      hoverTable.style.position = 'absolute';
      hoverTable.style.top = mainTable.offsetTop + 'px';
      hoverTable.style.left = mainTable.offsetLeft + 'px';
      hoverTable.style.width = (cellWidth * 3) + 'px';
      hoverTable.style.height = (rowHeight * 3) + 'px';
      hoverTable.style.border = 'none';
      hoverTable.style.borderRadius = '0';
      hoverTable.style.boxShadow = 'none';
      hoverTable.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      hoverTable.style.borderWidth = '0';



      // add rows and cells to the hover table  
      for (var i = 0; i < numResources + 1; i++) {

        var row = document.createElement('tr');

        if (i == 0) {
          row.style.height = '32.5 px';
        } else {
          row.style.height = rowHeight + 'px';
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < 48; j++) {
          var cell = document.createElement('td');
          cell.style.width = cellWidth + 'px';
          row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        hoverTable.appendChild(row);
      }

      // add the hover table to the DOM
      mainTable.parentNode.insertBefore(hoverTable, mainTable.nextSibling);

      // add event listeners to the cells of the hover table
      var hoverCells = hoverTable.querySelectorAll('td');
      hoverCells.forEach(function (cell) {
        cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
          cell.classList.add('hover');
        });
        cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
          cell.classList.remove('hover');
        });
      });
    }

  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

/*.fc-timeline-slot-lane:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.fc-timeline-lane:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}*/


.fc-time-grid-container .fc-slats td:hover,
.fc-time-grid-container .fc-major td:hover {
  background-color:red;
}

.hover{
  background-color: red;
}


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.overlay-cell {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.overlay-cell.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


.hover-table{
  background-color: grey;
 
}




.hover-table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hover-table tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.29);
}

.hover-table td, th {
  position: relative;
}
.hover-table td:hover::after,
.hover-table th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.29);
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/*
.hover-table td:first-child {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
 
}

.hover-table tr:first-child {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}*/

.hover-table td {
 
  border: none;
}




/*način 2 za row hover*/
/*
.hover-table {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.fc-timeline-slots{
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.fc-timeline-body  .fc-scrollgrid-sync-table  tbody tr:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.6/index.global.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

[image]

[image]

I tried different things such as trying to get the `clientHeight` property for each row but I don't get current values. Then I tried using mouse position. I also tried using `pointer-events: none;` but then I can only show a row hover and not both column and row. I also tried `mouseenter` events but since `fullcalendar` has columns above row elements, I only get the hover element of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column highlight can be done by applying CSS to the hovered `.fc-timeline-slot-lane` element:

```css
.fc-timeline-slot-lane:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

For the row though, we cannot use the same `:hover` selector, since the above
`.fc-timeline-slot-lane` is covering the rows, so we'd need to add some JavaScript to help us. We can rewrite the `viewDidMount` to help us:

```css
/**
 * Hover row styling.
 */
.fc-timeline-lane.hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```js
viewDidMount: function ({ el }) {
  // Get the `clientX` and `clientY` from the `mousemove` event object. These
  // correspond to the mouse position in the webpage.
  const handle = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    // Get all elements that are at the mouse position.
    const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    // Get the horizontal row element that might be under the mouse.
    const lane = elements.find(element => element.matches('.fc-timeline-lane'));
    // If the `lane` does not have a `hover` class or if there is no
    // `.fc-timeline-lane` element under the mouse:
    if (!lane?.classList.contains('.hover')) {
      // Try to find the `.fc-timeline-lane` that has the `hover` class and
      // and remove it.
      el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-lane.hover')?.classList.remove('hover');
      // Add the `hover` class to our found `.fc-timeline-lane` element (if
      // any).
      lane?.classList.add('hover');
    }
  };

  // Get the container that has the columns and row elements.
  const timeSlots = el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-slots');
  // When the mouse starts to hover over the timeline, listen for mouse
  // movement.
  timeSlots.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    timeSlots.addEventListener('mousemove', handle);
  });
  // When the mouse no longer hovers over the timeline, stop listening for 
  // mouse movement.
  timeSlots.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    timeSlots.removeEventListener('mousemove', handle);
  });
}
```

For the red rectangle for the cell, we can use the column, and adjust its background with more JavaScript to position the red rectangle to match the row
we're hovering over:

```css
.fc-timeline-slot-lane:hover {
  background: lightgray linear-gradient(red, red) no-repeat left var(--top, 0px) / 100% var(--height, 0px);
}
```

The CSS variables, `--top` and `--height` will be passed through from JavaScript:

```js
viewDidMount: function ({ el }) {
  const handle = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    const lane = elements.find(element => element.matches('.fc-timeline-lane'));
    // Get the vertical slot we're hovering over, if any.
    const slot = elements.find(element => element.matches('.fc-timeline-slot-lane'));
    if (!lane?.classList.contains('.hover')) {
      el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-lane.hover')?.classList.remove('hover');
      lane.classList.add('hover');
    }
    // If not hovering over a slot, or this slot does not already have
    // background coordinates:
    if (!slot?.style.getPropertyValue('--top')) {
      // Remove background coordinates from a different vertical slot (if any).
      el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-slot-lane[style]')?.removeAttribute('style');
    }
    // If we're hovering over a vertical and a horizontal slot:
    if (slot && lane) {
      // Get the position-parent-relative `top` and `height` of the horizontal
      // slot.
      const { offsetTop, offsetHeight } = lane;
      // Set the CSS variables to these.
      slot.style.setProperty('--top', `${offsetTop}px`);
      slot.style.setProperty('--height', `${offsetHeight}px`);
    }
  };

  const timeSlots = el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-slots');
  timeSlots.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    timeSlots.addEventListener('mousemove', handle);
  });
  timeSlots.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    timeSlots.removeEventListener('mousemove', handle);
  });
}
```

Here it is all put together:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.6,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    resourceGroupField: 'building',
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    resources: [
      { id: '1', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '2', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '3', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '4', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '5', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '6', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '11', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '21', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '31', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '41', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '51', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '61', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '111', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '211', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '311', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '411', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '511', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '611', title: 'Resource C' },

      { id: '19', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '29', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '39', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '49', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '59', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '69', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '191', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '291', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '319', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '419', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '519', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '619', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '1191', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '2191', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '3191', title: 'Resource C' },
      { id: '4191', title: 'Resource A' },
      { id: '5191', title: 'Resource B' },
      { id: '6191', title: 'Resource C' },
    ],
    events: [
      { resourceId: '1', start: '2023-05-02T02:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
      { resourceId: '2', start: '2023-05-02T05:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T09:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
      { resourceId: '3', start: '2023-05-02T03:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T08:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
      { resourceId: '4', start: '2023-05-02T06:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T12:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
      { resourceId: '5', start: '2023-05-02T08:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T13:00:00', title: 'event 5' },
      { resourceId: '6', start: '2023-05-02T10:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T14:00:00', title: 'event 6' },
      { resourceId: '1', start: '2023-05-02T13:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T18:00:00', title: 'event 7' },
      { resourceId: '2', start: '2023-05-02T10:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T14:00:00', title: 'event 8' },
      { resourceId: '3', start: '2023-05-02T08:00:00', end: '2023-05-02T12:30:00', title: 'event 9' }
    ],

    eventContent: function (arg) {

      var event = arg.event;

      var customHtml = '';

      customHtml += "<span class='r10 font-xxs font-bold' style='overflow: hidden;'>" + event.title + "</span>";

      customHtml += "<span class='r10 highlighted-badge font-xxs font-bold'> <br/> jkaSDHLKJahsdlkjAHS</span>";


      return { html: customHtml }
    },

    eventDidMount: function (info) {

    },





    viewDidMount: function ({ el }) {
      const handle = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
        const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
        const lane = elements.find(element => element.matches('.fc-timeline-lane'));
        const slot = elements.find(element => element.matches('.fc-timeline-slot-lane'));
        if (!lane?.classList.contains('.hover')) {
          el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-lane.hover')?.classList.remove('hover');
          lane?.classList.add('hover');
        }
        if (!slot?.style.getPropertyValue('--top')) {
          el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-slot-lane[style]')?.removeAttribute('style');
        }
        if (slot && lane) {
          const { offsetTop, offsetHeight } = lane;
          slot.style.setProperty('--top', `${offsetTop}px`);
          slot.style.setProperty('--height', `${offsetHeight}px`);
        }
      };
      
      const timeSlots = el.querySelector('.fc-timeline-slots');
      timeSlots.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        timeSlots.addEventListener('mousemove', handle);
      });
      timeSlots.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        timeSlots.removeEventListener('mousemove', handle);
      });
    }

  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

/*.fc-timeline-slot-lane:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.fc-timeline-lane:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}*/


.fc-time-grid-container .fc-slats td:hover,
.fc-time-grid-container .fc-major td:hover {
  background-color:red;
}

.hover{
  background-color: red;
}


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.overlay-cell {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.overlay-cell.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


.hover-table{
  background-color: grey;
 
}




.hover-table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hover-table tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.29);
}

.hover-table td, th {
  position: relative;
}
.hover-table td:hover::after,
.hover-table th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.29);
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/*
.hover-table td:first-child {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
 
}

.hover-table tr:first-child {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}*/

.hover-table td {
 
  border: none;
}




/*način 2 za row hover*/
/*
.hover-table {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.fc-timeline-slots{
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.fc-timeline-body  .fc-scrollgrid-sync-table  tbody tr:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
*/

.fc-timeline-slot-lane:hover {
  background: lightgray linear-gradient(red, red) no-repeat left var(--top, 0px) / 100% var(--height, 0px);
}

.fc-timeline-lane.hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.6/index.global.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```